# How to link multiple auth providers using Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a project, where it is possible to create a new user through a CMS system. Here, it is also possible for the user to log in with Google as well as email and password.

If the user chooses to log in with Google, the Cloud Function `onCreateUser` is triggered. If the user email already exists in the database, I would like to link that auth provider (login method) to the existing user within this cloud function and vice versa.

For web, you can use `linkWithCredential` but I have not found a way to do this using Firebase Cloud Functions.

Comment: What do you mean by "add that auth provider to the existing user"?

Comment: In firebase authentication, it is possible to log in using different providers like Facebook, Google, or Email and Password. So when a user chooses to log in with a different provider than they have done before, I want to check if that user already exists and then link that new auth provider to their existing user instead of creating a new user with a different auth provider.

It is possible to do it for web using `linkWithCredential` but I don't see any way to do the same using cloud functions.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but tell us which provider with which provider would you like to link.

Comment: I would like to link the Google provider and the Email/Password provider to the same user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your last comment:

> I would like to link the Google provider and the Email/Password provider to the same user.

That is the default behavior. If a user signs in using email and password and later signs in using Google provider, their account sign-in method is automatically converted to Google. There is nothing special that you should do. There is no need to link the accounts. Why? Because according to the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users), Google is considered a **trusted** provider:

> - Trusted providers:
>
> > Google (for @gmail.com addresses)

And:

> - Untrusted providers:
>
> > Email / Password without email verification

In Firebase Authentication, by default, a user can have **only one** account per email address. This is done to prevent users from creating multiple accounts using the same email address with different authentication providers. By the time I'm answering this question, I can say that Firebase Authentication has the concept of a preferred provider for certain email addresses and unfortunately, there is currently no way to change this behavior.

On the other hand, if a user signs in with Google provider first and later tries to sign in using email and password, an error will be thrown saying that the user already exists. And it makes sense since the user has already used that email before.

In this case, there are two ways in which you can solve this problem. When you get such an error, you can check the provider used to create the account, and notify the user through a message to use the authentication provider which was selected to create the account in the first place, in this case, Google.

The second option would be to allow the user to have multiple accounts using the same email address with different authentication providers. This option can be enabled directly in the [Firebase Console](https://firebase.google.com/), in the Authentication section.

Comment: Hey Caroline. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Yes thank you very much for your answer, now it makes more sense why the auth provider gets overridden.